# get value from function using python

Tags: python, json, function, key-value, firebase

I have a python function.

```
def v():
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.gosquared.com/v2/concurrents?api_key=xxxxx&site_token=xxxx&presenter=old')
    data = json.load(response) 
    print data
```

and I have a firebase

```
f = Firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/channel/1/status/viewers')
r = f.update({'viewers': 'v()'})
```

I want the value of that key:value pair to be the returned value from the v() function.

I've tried 'v()', "v()", and v() to no avail.

What am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: I probably have to make the function a variable, then put the variable in the value spot....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should `return` a value. It's just printing and not returning nything

Try this:

```
def v():
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.gosquared.com/v2/concurrents?api_key=xxxxx&site_token=xxxx&presenter=old')
    data = json.load(response) 
    #comment the below line if you don't want to print data and simply want to return it
    print data
    return data
```

**UPDATE**:
If you want to store the returned data to a variable then:

```
returned_data = v()
```

Comment: glad to help! If that solves your problem, upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: what's the advantages of storing it in a var, rather than just calling the function in the value place

Comment: If you don't need the return value for something else, there is no advantage at all.

Comment: As per your comment `I probably have to make the function a variable, then put the variable in the value spot.... `, i updated my answer, though it's just an extra step if you don't want the returned data to be used later in same code.

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns nothing. Try `return data` instead of (or after) `print data`.

Comment: figured. DUH! simple and plain!